# Remove watched variable in Xcode 4.5.2

Tags: debugging, xcode4.5, lldb, watch

I could watch a variable though "Watch 'variable'" in the Xcode debug area, and it works because Xcode breaks when the watched variable varies. But as I see nothing like "watch window", how could I remove the watched variable? or see the variables I'm watching? Through LLDB command?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can disable or delete watchpoints through the Breakpoint navigator in Xcode.  (View > Navigators > Show Breakpoint Navigator).  You can also do it through the lldb console window with the `watch delete` command.